# Move comments from task to following task

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

Camunda has the option to write a comment to a task. The current problem is that they get lost in the following task after the previous task has been completed. Is there any way to move the comments from task to task over a complete process instance?
Maybe it can be done via variables if anybody knows a way to access it in the Camunda modeler?

Answer (score 1):

The follow up task doesn't exist yet, so you cannot store comments on it.

What should work:

Register a taskListener on Task#complete, read the comment and store it in a global process variable.
On the next task, use a taskListener on create to read the comment variable and write to the (new) tasks comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are accessing the task information.
The task service has a method: **getProcessInstanceComments**
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.15/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html#getProcessInstanceComments-java.lang.String-

In an expression it could look like:

```
${taskService.getProcessInstanceComments(execution.processInstanceId).toString()}
```